# Update table with condition matching

Tags: sql, join, subquery

Blockquote

I'm trying to mark with an 'X' all the records that match the fields Clave_Rel from table A with numero_cue from table B.
I'm doing something like this :

> UPDATE clientes_MP_julio SET MARCA_X 
>   = 'X' WHERE clientes_MP_julio.NUMERO_CUE = (SELECT CLAVE_REL FROM PAGOS A INNER JOIN clientes_MP_julio B ON A.CLAVE_REL =B.numero_cue)

But i'm receiving the message:

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

I understand why the message, but I don't know how to solve it! Sorry... I'm new on this! and I really appreciate your help, hoping that someday I can help too.
Thanks!

Comment: Your `=` should probably be `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the subquery, just a simple inner join. The problem with your syntax is that the `=` sign expects a single value on the right side, whereas the subquery is returning multiple values.

Try the following:

```
UPDATE
    clientes_MP_julio
SET 
    c.MARCA_X = 'X'
FROM
    clientes_MP_julio AS c
    INNER JOIN
    PAGOS AS p
    ON
        p.CLAVE_REL = c.NUMERO_CUE
```